# What determines the booster types received when releasing a blade?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

What determines the type of boosters I receive after releasing a blade? Is it based on the type of blade I'm releasing or is it random?

[image: Getting boosters after releasing a blade]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [Xenoblade Chronicles 2 wiki](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Blade_(XC2)#Releasing_Blades) states:

> Releasing yields certain resources to the player, usually boosters corresponding to the Blade's element. The quantity and type of items received upon release is determined by the Strength of Blade.

Here's a chart:

[image]

◆ = booster corresponds to the Element of the released Blade
❖ = booster received is random

And according to several sources:

- **Bravery** Booster has Fire and Water affinity
- **Truth** Booster has a Wind and Ice affinity
- **Compassion** Booster has Electric and Earth affinity
- **Justice** Booster has a Light and Dark affinity

Comment: Extra note: If you don't have enough inventory space for the boosters you get, the game pretends you didn't get them at all (doesn't tell you anything).